# Efficient way to count occurrences of a key in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This was asked in on-site Microsoft interview.

Count the number of occurrences of a given key in an array.

I answered linear search because the elements may be scattered in the
array. Say the key is found in the beginning and at the end. So we
need to scan the entire array.

Next he asked what if the array is sorted?

Thought for a while and said I'll use linear search again. Because the
repetitions of the key if present can be anywhere in the array. As an
optimization I also said if first and last array elements are same you
can take the array length as the answer.

Is my analysis correct in both the cases?

Example:

```
Input = [0 0 1 1 1 2 2 3 3], key = 1, Answer = 3
Input = [0 0 2 2 3 3],       key = 1, Answer = 0
```

Answer (score 31):

For unsorted array there is not much we can do other than linear search.

For sorted array you can do it in `O(logN)` using a slightly modified binary search:

- Find the index of first occurrence of
  `key`, call it `f`.
- Find the index of last occurrence of
  `key`, call it `l`.
- If the `key` exists in the array `l-f+1`
  is the answer.

Finding the first occurrence:

`arr[i]` is the first occurrence of `key` iff

- `arr[i] == key` **and** either

  - `i == 0` ( it's the first element of 
    the array) **or**
  - `arr[i-1] != key` (it's not the first
    element of the array and element to
    it's left is different)

You can slightly modify the binary search to find the first occurrence.
In a binary search you terminate the search when you find `arr[mid] == key`.
Modify the condition such that you terminate the search when you find the ***first*** occurrence instead of ***any*** occurrence.

Algorithm:

```
low = 0
high = arrSize - 1 

while low <=  high

  mid = (low + high) / 2

  //if arr[mid] == key         // CHANGE
  if arr[mid] == key AND ( mid == 0 OR arr[mid-1] != key )
    return mid
  //else if ( key < arr[mid] ) // CHANGE
  else if ( key <= arr[mid] ) 
    high = mid - 1
  else
    low = mid + 1        
  end-if

end-while

return -1
```

Similarly you can find the last occurrence.

Comment: +1, but `mid = (low + high) / 2` should be inside the loop. Also, I think you can get rid of the rather-complicated first `if`, but it's arguable if getting rid of it is less complicated or more complicated.

Comment: @IVlad: Thanks for pointing. What simpler alternative do you suggest for the first if?

Comment: You can collapse the binary search functions into one, especially if you remove the break-early condition which might end up saving a few cycles in practice.

Comment: I was thinking of replacing the while condition with `low < high`, removing the first `if`, changing the next one to `if (arr[mid] <= key) high = mid`, then at the end checking if `arr[low] == key`.

Comment: @marcog: That can be done. I kept them separate to make it a bit clearer. @IVlad: That can be done too. I wanted to make as little changes as possible w.r.t the std BS.

Answer (score 9):

For once, I will propose an implementation in C++.

```
size_t count(std::vector<int> const& vec, int key)
{
  auto p = std::equal_range(vec.begin(), vec.end(), key);
  return std::distance(p.first, p.second);
}
```

`equal_range` uses a binary search, the result is equivalent to:

```
std::make_pair(std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), key),
               std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), key));
```

but the implementation should makes it slightly faster, even though all are in O(log N) (in terms of number of comparison).

Comment: @T33C: then both the iterators point to the same element, and therefore (since they delimit a half-opened range) the distance from one to the other is 0 :)

Comment: +1. Nice shot, but he should know C++ to understand this :-) Anyway, why std::vector? What if I decide to use, say, boost::array? Use templates :-)

Comment: @Stas: Yes, I usually demonstrate in Python, but it was too good an opportunity to show off C++. It's not that often that you can find a less verbose alternative in C++ :p As for templates... I considered it, but was afraid it would be even more confusing to non-C++ users. The syntax is *peculiar* to say the least :)

Comment: Nice use of lower_bound() and upper_bound() in C++, but I think that the interviewer would expect a handmade solution in the OP's coding interview.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: Maybe, maybe not. I find it best, in interviews, to start discussing from high-level to low-level: this allows the interviewer to decide how low-level to get, and this allows me to show-case that I do not suffer from NIH syndrome.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int binarysearch(int a[],int n,int k,bool searchfirst){
    int result=-1;
    int low=0,high=n-1;
    while(low<=high){
        int mid=(low+high)/2;
        if(a[mid]==k)  {
              result=mid; 
           if(searchfirst)
              high=mid-1; 
            else
              low=mid+1;
    }
    else if(k<a[mid])  high=mid-1;
    else low=mid+1;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){
    int a[]={1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,7,7};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    int x=6;
    int firstindex=binarysearch(a,n,x,true);
    printf("%d\n",firstindex);
    if(firstindex==-1){
        printf("elment not found in the array:\n ");
    }
    else {
        int lastindex=binarysearch(a,n,x,false);
        printf("%d\n",lastindex);
        printf("count is = %d", lastindex-firstindex+1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Some explanation of why this is better would help people looking at this question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive version of binary search

```
int modifiedbinsearch_low(int* arr, int low, int high , int key)
{   
    if(low==high) return high ; 

    int mid = low + (high-low) /2;

    if(key >  arr[mid] ) { modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,mid + 1 , high,key);  } 
    else  { modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,low,mid,key);  }  
}
int modifiedbinsearch_high(int* arr, int low, int high , int key)
{   
    if(low==high) return high ; 

    int mid = low + (high-low) /2;

    if(key <  arr[mid] ) { modifiedbinsearch_high(arr,low,mid,key);  } 
    else  { modifiedbinsearch_high(arr,mid+1,high,key);  } 

}
```

.

```
int low = modifiedbinsearch_low( ...)

int high = modifiedbinsearch_high( ...)
```

`(high - low)`  gives the number of keys

Answer (score 1):

**
 **Time Complexity** = O ( lg N )   where N is the size of array

** Arguments for binarySearchXXXXX:**

1. int[] array  is a sorted array of length >= 1
2. int k : key to search

**

```
package array;

 public class BinarySearchQuestion {

public static int binarySearchFirst(int[] array, int k) {
    int begin = 0;
    int end = array.length-1;
    int mid = -1;
    while (begin <= end) {
        mid = begin + (end - begin) / 2;
        if (array[mid] < k) {
            begin = mid + 1;
        } else {
            end = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    //System.out.println("Begin index :: " + begin + " ,  array[begin] " + array[begin]);
    return (begin <= array.length - 1  && begin >= 0 && array[begin] != k) ? -1 : begin;
    //      return begin;
}

public static int binarySearchLast(int[] array, int k) {
    int begin = 0;
    int end = array.length - 1;
    int mid = -1;
    while (begin <= end) {
        mid = begin + (end - begin) / 2;
        if (array[mid] > k) {
            end = mid - 1;
        } else {
            begin = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    //System.out.println("Last index end :: " + end + " ,  array[mid] " + array[end]);
    return (end <= array.length - 1  && end >= 0 &&  array[end] != k) ? -1 : end;
    //return end;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
             //     int[] array = { 0, 1,1,1, 2, 3, 4,4,4,5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5,6,6,6,6, 6, 7, 7, 7,
             //             7, 8, 9 };
            //      int[] array = {-1, 0,1, 1,1,2,3};
    int[] array = {1,1,1};

    int low = binarySearchFirst(array, 1);
    int high = binarySearchLast(array, 1);
    int total = (high >= low && low != -1 && high != -1) ? ( high - low + 1 ): 0;
    System.out.println("Total Frequency " + total);
}

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this for the sorted part, with O(logN) time complexity?

```
int count(int a[], int k, int l, int h) {
  if (l>h) {
    return 0;
  }
  int mid = (l+h)/2;
  if (k > a[mid]) {
     return count(a, k, mid+1, h);
  }
  else if (k < a[mid]) {
     return count(a, k, l, mid-1);
  }
  else {
     return count(a, k, mid+1, h) + count(a, k, l, mid-1) + 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

package arrays;

/*
 * Given a sorted array, find the number of times an element occured.
 * Binary search O(lgn)
 * */

public class NumberOfN {

```
static int bSearchLeft(int[] arr, int start, int end, int n){

    while(start < end){

        int mid = (start + end)>>1;
        if(arr[mid] < n){
            start = mid + 1;
        }else{
            end = mid;
        }

    }

    return end;
}

static int bSearchRight(int[] arr, int start, int end, int n){

    while(start < end){

        int mid = (start + end)>>1;
        if(arr[mid] <= n){
            start = mid + 1;
        }else{
            end = mid;
        }

    }

    return end;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr = new int[]{3,3,3,3};
    int n = 3;
    int indexLeft = bSearchLeft(arr, 0, arr.length, n);
    int indexRight = bSearchRight(arr, 0, arr.length, n);
    System.out.println(indexLeft + " " +indexRight);
    System.out.println("Number of occurences: " + (indexRight - indexLeft));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this using Linear as well as Binary Search.
But Linear Search will be O(n). Binary Search will give O(Logn).
Hence it's better to use Binary search.
The complete program is :

```
public class Test4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int a[] = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6,6,6,6,6,66,7}; 
     int x =  6; 

         System.out.println(fix(a,x));
}

private static int fix(int[] a, int x) {
    int res = 0 ;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int ch = a[i];
        if(x == ch) {res++ ;}
    }
    return res;
}
}
```

There is another follow up question that's asked is : 1st and last occurence of a given number in a sorted array.

```
class Occurence1 {

    public static void findFirstAndLast(int a[], int x) {

        int first = -1, last = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (x == a[i]) {
                if (first == -1) {
                    first = i;
                }
                // update last
                last = i;
            } // if

        } // for                                                                           
        if (first != -1) {
            System.out.println("First Occurrence = " + first);
            System.out.println("Last Occurrence = " + last);
        } 
    }// end1

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 8 };
        int x = 8;
        findFirstAndLast(arr, x);
    }
}
```

In Python :

```
def findFirstAndLast(a, x):
    first = -1 ; last = -1
    for i in range(len(a)) :
        if(x == a[i]): 
            if(first == -1):first = i 

         # update last if the first contains oter value than -1    
        last = i

    if(first != -1):
        print("first => ",first)
        print("last =>", last)       


a = [1, 2, 3,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 10, 10]
x = 10
findFirstAndLast(a, x)
```

Answer (score -1):

If the array is unsorted, yes, linear search from one end to the other is as good as it gets.

However, if the array is sorted, you can do better than linear time by applying binary or interpolation search techniques.

Treat the problem as the same as "Find the number X in a sorted list" with the added detail of "then scan left and right to determine how many times X appears".  The first part, the search, is best done with binary or interpolation search in most cases.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search

Comment: What if all numbers in the list are X? Then this is going to degenerate to O(N). Solution is to use a slightly modified binary search that always shifts the right boundary left when you're on the value you're looking for. This will find you the first occurrence in logarithmic time. Then do the same, but shifting the left boundary right for the last occurrence.

Comment: marcog - Is your approach same as codaddict's ?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you're right for unsorted array, but for sorted array you can use binary search to locate one occurence of the element and once that one occurence is found only scan adjacent elements until you find mismatches and then stop.

Comment: @codaddict: Well, yes, it is linear if there're lots of those values. I guess binary search can be used for finding the range, but this will be quite complicated.

Comment: It's precisely the same thing you've done in the first step. What is so complicated about that?